# i want to make a multiply inside loop,but the value not increasing

Tags: php, for-loop

i have a homework like this

Imaginative Tree

An imaginative tree grows in a garden. The tree only grows 1 m long in autumn and 2 times the height of the tree in spring. Make a program that determines the highest tree after Y years with the initial height X m.
in 1 year spring come first

i've tried to put multiple symbol inside the loop,

```
 <?php 
 $holddata =0;
 $length =0
 function randomtree($year,$firstlength){
  for ($i=0; $i < $year ; $i++) { 

      $holddata= $firstlength* 2;
      $length= $holddata+1;

  }
  echo $length;
  }
  echo randomtree(2,3);
```

but the value not increasing ,i expected the $firstlength*2 and add 1 on it then loop them 2 times so the result will be 15 ,( 3*2+1=7 ,7*2+1=15)

Comment: You are overriding your variables every iteration. HINT: You are not reassigning any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the value of `$firstlength` as the basis of the start of each calculation and assign the result to it for the next iteration.  This code also returns the result rather than `echo`ing out out.

So to simplify your code you can use...

```
function randomtree($year,$firstlength){
    for ($i=0; $i < $year ; $i++) {
        $firstlength = ($firstlength* 2)+1;
    }
    return $firstlength;
}
echo randomtree(2,3);
```